# Return JSON response (from a Django view) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, django

I'm trying to get a JSON response in AJAX when I type in the E-mail field.
I get the response on the console, like

```
{response: "example@gmail.com is already in use.", email: "example@gmail.com"}
email: "example@gmail.com"
response:"example@gmail.com is already in use."
```

or

```
{response: "This field is required..", email: ""}
email: ""
response:"This field is required."
```

but I don't know how to use the response as a Javascript value. I'd like to use it to have an automatic message that tells if the E-mail is available or not.

Here's what I've come to until now.
My **template** + **script**

```
<form data-parsley-validate id="form" method="post" action="/register/" enctype="multipart/form-data">

{% csrf_token %}

{{ form.as_p }}
<p id="email-error"></p>

<input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="Register" />
</form>

<script>
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
            // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
        }
    }
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#id_email").focusout(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
        var email = $('#id_email').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/email_check/",
            type: "POST",            
            dataType: "json",
            data : { 
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken, 
                email: email
            },
            success: function(result) {
                document.getElementById("email-error").innerHTML = result;
            },
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

The **view.py**

```
@requires_csrf_token
def email_check(request):
    email = request.POST.get('email', False)
    if request.is_ajax():
        if email:
            query_email = User.objects.filter(email=email)
            if query_email.exists():
                res = "{0} is already in use.".format(email)
            else:
                res = "This E-mail is ok."
            ajax_vars = {'response': res, 'email': email}
            json_data = json.dumps(ajax_vars)
        else:
            res = "This field is required."
            ajax_vars = {'response': res, 'email': email}
            json_data = json.dumps(ajax_vars)

        return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
```

With this code, the message i get back on "#email-error" is: **[object Object]**
What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: `result` is an object by the looks of it - you probably want to use `document.getElementById("email-error").innerHTML = result.response;`

Comment: That's it, thanks :)